# Build SLN File on Linux

Tags: linux, build, project

I'm trying to build a sln file on ubuntu with mono-msbuild.
It says I should install Windows SDK, because my Project depends on it. 
So are there any Ways to install Windows SDK on ubuntu or bypass that?

Error Code:

> Microsoft.Cpp/v4.0/V140/Platforms/Win32/PlatformToolsets                           /v140/Toolset.targets(34,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not                            found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution"

Answer (score 0):

From Show applications:
[Show applications Icon Bottom Left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iicgB.png)
Open Ubuntu software which will open the snap store:
[Ubuntu Software  Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu72r.png)
In the search bar type: .NET Core SDK. This will find the .NET Core SDK and you can install it from there. In my case, I have already installed it, so my screen shows it as installed. If you have not installed it then there is a button to install it.

[.NET Core SDK snap (Already installed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6MaR.png)